What made Steve thank Sidney?
Susie and guitarist Steve were having a romantic moment behind the club, during which
Steve expressed his enjoyment of the Chinese food they shared. Their moment was interrupted by a
press agent Sidney, who asked if he could join them:

Sidney: Where are those glossy prints you promised me? I can't place
'em later than tonight.
Steve: Thanks very much just the same. Let's forget about it, huh?

What made Steve thank Sidney?

Thank you, but I no longer need your services. It's a polite way of saying "f*ck off" because there's a lady present
